# .done not fired on ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function that makes a ajax call. The `.done` doesn't seems to be firing. I checked for the error on my console. It says

[image]

```js
function getIncidentInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../page_components/statsboard/stats.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function(response) {
        incidentAr = response;
        for (var i in incidentAr) {
            var zaNorth = parseInt(incidentAr[i].zaNorth);
            ......
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Status: " + status + " Error: " + error);
        console.log(xhr);
    });
}
```

I asked my friend to try the same piece of code and it works.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors - some of us are behind firewalls and can't see your error message......

Comment: “Unexpected token `<`” is indicative of the retrieved file _not being JSON_. Look at the object’s `responseText` property: it starts with `<br />`.

Comment: Your ajax request expects a json response, but instead it's receiving an HTML. When it tries to parse the HTML response to json the error pops.

Comment: @user6185666 That edit didn’t change anything. The code block was already highlighted as JavaScript. The edit suggestion should have been rejected.

Answer (score 0):

The script in `stats.php` is throwing an XDebug error and is returning HTML describing the error instead of the JSON you are expecting. Loading the `stats.php` page in a browser, or check your PHP logs to find out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `.always(response)` instead of `.done(response)`.  Some services return non 200 codes with a response body to describe the error.
2. Check `response.responseJSON`, `response.responseText`, and `response.responseXML`.  You may have to state `response.responseJSON = eval(respaonse.responseText)`.

However, I see that the `responseText` is of HTML type, so my guess (and I say this because you're getting a 200 status and not a 404 or 500) is that you are getting a more generic server error that is rendering a response from a route you did not intend to query.